# Total Number of distinguishable paths

Tags: probability, statistics, hamiltonian-path

I found a lot of things distribing a number of paths across a grid, but not quite what my question is. I'm looking for the total number of distinguishable paths through X number of points. For example, let's say i have 5 points A - E as seen below

```
A    B    C    D    E
```

For example a few of my paths could be as follows:

```
ABCDE    (Don't skip any)
ACDE     (Skip B)
ABDE     (Skip B)
ABD      (Skip C and E)
... etc
```

I'd like to find the total paths for two cases. 1) I can only go in increasing order (ABCDE would be valid, but not ACBDE). 2) where I can go in any order. In either case a point cannot be repeated (can't go ABACDE for example)

For case 1, i can see this as occupation problem where i have r = 5 balls and n = 5 cells, and then need to find all the distributions with at least 1 empty cell, but no more than 3 empty cells. if i know that, then i can just add 1 to it for the case there no cells are empty. The problem with that is, i might have a case where 2 balls are in cell A and 3 in C, and another with 3 balls in A and 2 in C. For my case, these are the exact same path. I'm just not sure how to do the math.... is it simple 2^5 (2^x for the general case)?

For Case 2, I pretty lost on how to think about that one. If anyone could at least point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it. Thanks!!

Comment: I think,
case one) $1*4*3*2*1$
casetwo ) $4*3*2*1*1$

Comment: aren't those the same thing though? 1*4! = 4!*1. i would expect case 1 have have fewer paths since there are more constraints on it than case 2.

Comment: This is my toughts, when you move in ascending order, you have two fixed points, namely, A, E, therefore, you have 3, 2, 1 possible points, respectively

Comment: excuse me, it was typo, case one must be, i think, 1*3*2*1*1

Comment: There must be two fixed points, but they don't necessarily need to be A and E (sorry, i didn't make that very clear in the problem) , but even so, i can quickly come up with more than 6 paths that have at least A and E in them.

Comment: I mean, E is the biggest value, so must be placed at the end, A is the lowest value so mus be placed at the begginings, this is what I understand at that moment

Comment: You said, we must not use repetitive letters, consequently, we get:
1*3*2*1*1 different paths

Comment: but i can come up with the following paths, even if i have A and E at the beginning and the end. ABCDE, ACDE, ABDE, ABCE, ABE, ACE, ADE, AE.   Which i believe is just 2^3 paths. Since that's the case, I'm guessing that my initial thought for Case 1 is 2^5 paths (or 2^x for the general case)

Comment: I thought, we cannot omit the letters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have said for the first $2^5=32$ as you suggest, and in general $2^n$.

For the second, I would say $1 + 5\times(1 + 4\times( 1+ 3\times(1+ 2\times(1+1)))) = 326$.  The general value would be $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{k!}$.

But from your comments it seems that your paths apparently need to start a a particular point and finish at a different point, so the $1$ path with no points and the $5$ paths with just one point would need to be subtracted, leaving $26$ paths for the first question and $320$ for the second. In general you need to subtract $n+1$.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I believe this was the answer i was looking for. Thanks for the explanation!